# Keep variable value after quitting the program MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, storage

I made a struct with CStrings in my MFC program. I also did a pointer so I can send it to my CMyDoc class. How can I save the variable, that the value stays after quitting the program?

Comment: Save the data to a file? You might want to read about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your CMyDoc is inherited from CDocument you need to override the Serialize method. More info available here:

[Serializing Data to and from Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz0h1c2h%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX)

> The MFC Application Wizard places a skeletal override of the CDocument
>   member function Serialize in the document class it creates for you.
>   After you have implemented your application's member variables, you
>   can fill in your Serialize override with code that sends the data to
>   an "archive object" connected to a file. A CArchive object is similar
>   to the cin and cout input/output objects from the C++ iostream
>   library. However, CArchive writes and reads binary format, not
>   formatted text.

[CDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y59b487w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> Override the CObject::Serialize member function in your document class
>   to write and read the document's data to and from disk.